# What is a good method to refresh all the records in a table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an existing table that must be refreshed regularly.
The table cannot be deleted, the records in the table can. 
Is it possible to do this with a delete all records and append new records in one query?
What is a good method to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need 2 queries, but you can do it one procedure: delete, then insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could allow the table to be deleted, one query would do it:

```
SELECT * INTO TempTable FROM YourTable;
```

Otherwise, two queries must be used: First a *delete* query, then an *append* query:

```vb
Public Function RefreshTable()

    Dim AppendSql As String
    Dim DeleteSql As String

    AppendSql = "<Your append SQL>"  ' Copy/paste from a working query.
    DeleteSql = "<Your delete SQL>"  ' Copy/paste from a working query.

    CurrentDb.Execute DeleteSql
    CurrentDb.Execute AppendSql

End Sub
```

Comment: The table cannot be deleted. I'm searching now to examples how to do it in VBA.

Comment: It's nothing more than running the two queries.

Comment: Thank you, I have no experience in VBA for Access. I try to find example code I can edit for my solution. If you would have any I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: I've expanded the code to a function. Copy this into a new module, compile and save. Edit the two SQL commands and save. Call the function from, say, a button-click of a button on a form.

Comment: I'm eternally gratefull